# SQL Dynamic column handling in Table during data load

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need to design a Table in Oracle/SQL & data will be upload via Java/C# application via CSV with 50 fields (mapped to columns of Table). How to design Table/DB with below constraints during data importing from CSV

- CSV may have new fields being added to existing 50 fields.

> In that case instead of adding column to table manually & load data. How can we design table for smooth/automatic file handling with dynamic fields

EX:

CSV has **S_ID, S_NAME, SUBJECT, MARK_VALUE** fields in it

```
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
| S_ID | S_NAME  | SUBJECT     | MARK_VALUE |
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
|    1 | Stud    | SUB_1       |         50 |
|    2 | Stud    | SUB_2       |         60 |
|    3 | Stud    | SUB_3       |         70 |
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

What if CSV has new field "RANK" (similar more fields) added to it & i need to store all new fields in Table.

Please suggest DB design for this consideration

Answer (score 0):

So there are few approaches come to my mind, one of the way would be having metadata(Record) information in one table (column name, data type, any constraint) and have another free form table with large enough no. of columns which will hold the data. Use the metadata table while inserting data into this table to maintain data integrity and other stuff.